# Custom domains, App Domain with a single facebook app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api

I am building a [candidate tracking system](http://www.keeprecruiting.com) called KeepRecruiting that allows users to post vacancies to their facebook pages. But I also support custom domains like http://careers.dharanasoft.com and subdomains like http://dharana.keeprecruiting.com. I understand that I can put multiple domains in the app domain field. However, I am not sure if it would allow domains as diverse as these. Also, is there a limit on the number of domains that I could add?

Answer (score 0):

I got around this by adding my second unrelated domain as the "Mobile Web URL" for the app on http://developers.facebook.com/apps/. However that's clearly a hack and will only work for two of your diverse domain names. Take a look at the answers to these similar questions too: [What’s the correct/best approach to have multiple unrelated App Domains associated to a Facebook application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9786201/575530), [Is it possible to configure a Facebook app to be used across multiple domains?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7553607/575530), and [Facebook Connect for one application with multiple domains?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4431574/575530).