# What’s the correct/best approach to have multiple unrelated App Domains associated to a Facebook application?

Tags: facebook, dns

I have an application hosted on Azure and accessed through a web page. Authentication to the application is handled by signing in through Facebook. The application is not a Facebook canvas application, though it can share some activity to a user's Facebook stream.

I have two URLs to access my service; one http://projectgreenwich.cloudapp.net/ points to the site in the cloud (on Azure) while the other http://projectgreenwich.research.microsoft.com relies on DNS to give the application a more official looking URL. My problem is that in the Facebook application set-up (http://developers.facebook.com/apps/) I can only give one "App Domain" for the Facebook authentication to pass back to. I can fork from that domain, e.g. having projectgreenwich.cloudapp.net, projectgreenwichlocal.cloudapp.net, projectgreenwichtest.cloudapp.net, etc. But if I try to add a different domain (e.g. projectgreenwich.research.microsoft.com) I get an error when I save the Facebook app settings.

My solution has been to add http://projectgreenwich.research.microsoft.com as what Facebook term the "Mobile Web URL" for the app. This fixes my immediate problem (authentication on Facebook from http://projectgreenwich.research.microsoft.com works) but it leaves me uncomfortable about two things:

1. It's a hack. The http://projectgreenwich.research.microsoft.com URL is no more a "Mobile Web URL" than the http://projectgreenwich.cloudapp.net/ is.
2. If I add other DNS entries resolving to http://projectgreenwich.cloudapp.net/ there's no further place to add them.

There are a couple of related answers on Stack Overflow that suggest this is not possible and that Facebook’s blog-post to the contrary is misleadingly worded, but I’m hoping things have changed:

- [Zachary Kestenbaum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/988990/zachary-kestenbaum)'s answer to [ginja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/628372/ginja)'s question "[Is it possible to configure a Facebook app to be used across multiple domains?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7553607/575530)" here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7722584/575530
- [Ross](https://stackoverflow.com/users/539394/ross)' answer to [Winaji](https://stackoverflow.com/users/540834/winaji)'s question "[Facebook Connect for one application with multiple domains?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4431574/575530)" here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4449914/575530

What’s the correct/best approach to have multiple unrelated App Domains associated to a Facebook application?